# Using PHP to populate Javascript Variables

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, csv

I'm trying to populate a Drop-Down menu from a csv file located on a network share.

I've come as far to get the file to create all the options successfully when the file is in the `wwwroot` folder however, now I'm faced with the external url reference issue.

Ajax does not support local `File:///` directories and when attempting to use the network share location it also fails: `\\Server\Folder\File.csv`

Is there any way to read the data from the csv file using php or other server-side language in order to perform my work on the data?

Code Below for your reference:

```
<script>
function SubmitBy(){
    $.ajax({
    url: encodeURI('./PrinterLookup.csv'),
    success: function(data) {

        var splitData=data.split("\n");
        for (var i = 0; i < splitData.length; i++) {
            var colData = splitData[i];
            var strucData = colData.substr(0, colData.indexOf("="));
        $('#SubmitBy').append("<option value=\"" + strucData + "\">" +
        strucData + "</option>");
}
    }
});
}
</script>
```

Looking for something like this,,, to bypass the ajax url limitation:

```
<script>
function SubmitBy(){
<?php
$Datapath = "\\Server\Folder\Document.csv";
$Data = file_get_contents($Datapath);
?>
var data = $Data;
        var splitData=data.split("\n");
        for (var i = 0; i < splitData.length; i++) {
            var colData = splitData[i];
            var strucData = colData.substr(0, colData.indexOf("="));
        $('#SubmitBy').append("<option value=\"" + strucData + "\">" +
        strucData + "</option>");
}
    }
});
}
</script>
```

Any assistance on this will be greatly appreciated.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you just do `var data = <?= $data; ?>`

Comment: Hi @Jackhardcastle Unfortunately didn't populate the variable.. Any ideas on how to find the exact breaking point?

Comment: Anyone got an update on this?
It appears that somehow the PHP is not executed and returns a null or empty value.

Answer (score 0):

in this line `var data = $Data;` you need to print `$Data` see below

```
<script>
function SubmitBy(){
<?php
$Datapath = "file:///Server/Folder/Document.csv";
$Data = file_get_contents($Datapath);
?>
var data = <?php echo $Data; ?> //correction here
        var splitData=data.split("\n");
        for (var i = 0; i < splitData.length; i++) {
            var colData = splitData[i];
            var strucData = colData.substr(0, colData.indexOf("="));
        $('#SubmitBy').append("<option value=\"" + strucData + "\">" +
        strucData + "</option>");
}
    }
});
}
</script>
```

Comment: So, I've tried this, but nothing happens, I'm suspecting that the URL may be incorrect? Using a Network share location IE. \\Server\Folder\Document.csv does not seem to return a value. Should I rather look for File://///Server/Folder/Document.csv?

Comment: try with updated url file:///Server/Folder/Document.csv

Comment: Still no luck, no data appears to be populating the php variable..

Comment: There should be `var data = <?php echo json_encode($data); ?>;`

Comment: why JSON  this will be CSV so comma separated values ??

Comment: Semicolon delimited ;

Comment: I've also tried changing the $Datapath to the same directory as the other files. IE: "./Document.csv".... This works when using ajax to call the file, however seems to not populate the variable when using the file_get_contents PHP function?

Answer (score -1):

Please check first this is .php file . 
If this is .php file.

```
<?php
  $Datapath = "\\Server\Folder\Document.csv";
  $Data = file_get_contents($Datapath);
?>
<script>
    function SubmitBy(){
    var data = <?php print_r( $data ); ?>;
            var splitData=data.split("\n");
            for (var i = 0; i < splitData.length; i++) {
                var colData = splitData[i];
                var strucData = colData.substr(0, colData.indexOf("="));
            $('#SubmitBy').append("<option value=\"" + strucData + "\">" +
            strucData + "</option>");
    }
        }
    });
    }
 </script>
```

Comment: Tried adding the "print_r" function, still not reading the data into the variable

Comment: please add explanation about what you did ?